# Is there is any way to get the appcenter config from env file in React Native

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-app-center, visual-studio-app-center-distribute

One of my android application is developed using React-Native and I have plans to distribute this using app-center as this app is for Internal users. In App-Center I have different projects (created new app) for the different environments - one for dev, one for uat and one for production.

My issue here is whenever I create build package (apk file) to deploy to App Center project, I need to manually change the app-center config. I have used .env [config](https://medium.com/differential/managing-configuration-in-react-native-cd2dfb5e6f7b) file to get config for different environment. But I can't use this to set app-center config. Can anyone guide me how I can automate this process by either configuring the app-center in .env file or somewhere in code?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a specific configuration for each build with the same code, you should use the [appcenter's environment variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/custom/variables/).

Just add an "app_secret" environment variable, and use a [pre build script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/custom/scripts/#pre-build) to create a **appcenter-config.json** file containing the app_secret

Comment: have a look @ https://blog.usejournal.com/react-native-config-and-appcenter-environment-variables-a1a3492ca6a0